# How can I add a button which gets my current location in Google Streetview to my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a button created in my view.

In the ViewModel, I wish to make it so that this button will open up Google Streetview and go to my current location.

Where can I find some resources for learning more about using the Google maps API with iPhone? I would like to allow users to save routes, among some other things.

How can I make it so that my button opens up Google Maps, in Streetview mode, at my current location? Can I do this within my app, without having to close my app and open Google maps/go back to my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear what you're asking. You say Google Maps, but then you say you want to stay within your application.

iOS includes the map kit, which lets you display maps. The maps are currently provided by Google, although it sounds like that may change in a future iOS release. Read up on MKMapView for more information. There are several sample apps included with the iOS SDK that show how to do different things with map kit.

If you want to link to a Google map street view, you will need to generate a Google URL, which should invoke the Google Maps application on the device. You'll need to consult the Google maps API documentation for information on how to do that.